# master project topic bigger then I expected

Tags: paper-submission

I am a master student in Germany. I want to submit master project (not thesis) in 2 month. project has 4 months duration and 8 credit.
I don't have enough experience in research area.

The problem is my topic have really big domain. I thought I can complete in 4 month. unfortunately it come bigger bigger when I research more.

my topic to optimize fulfillment of norm requirements by EN50128 with agile and project management tool.

How can I make it simple without loosing quality of paper? please someone guide me how can i do research, something wrong with my way of writing paper?

Comment: You have an advisor. It's their job to help you with this and they are in a better position to help you than random people on the internet. After all, your advisor will also grade your work.

Comment: By the way, unless it is somebody who is very well informed on project management, they won't know what "EN50128" is. Even the concept of "agile" is not necessarily going to be known to somebody who is uniformed on project management.